# Replace string in URL using HTACCESS

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to replace a string in my url.

I have this URL:

```
http://www.example.net/categories/Touchscreen-Tableta/Digitizer-Touchscreen-Tablete-Apple-iPad/
```

What i want:

```
http://www.example.net/categories/Touchscreen-Tableta/Touchscreen-Tablete-Apple-iPad/
```

I want to replace `Digitizer-Touchscreen` with `Touchscreen`

*I have tried all examples found on stackoverflow but failed.*

Comment: I've searched stackoverflow and tried to adapt all examples to my scenario, but couldn't get it to work. I'm not familiar with htaccess syntax and i think i was doing somethig wrong. I have adapted rewrite rules before and i got them to work, but this one got the better of me. I couldn't even cause errors with it, it would just ignore it.

Comment: Edit the question and provide examples of what you have tried.